# BlackBerry HelloWorld deploys in Eclipse under 8130 simulator but not 950

Tags: deployment, blackberry, build, eclipse-plugin, simulator

I followed the steps in www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/21

If I pick the 4.5.0 JDE with the 8130 simulator, I can navigate to the HelloWorld icon, click it, the app runs, I can hit breakpoints, etc.

I then switch to the 4.7.0 JDE, erase the simulator files (Blackberry | Erase Simulator File | Erase All), and change the simulator from Default to 9500 in Debug Configurations

When I run the simulator, I get the series of messages in the Eclipse Console window as the simulator comes up. If I then click on BB button to get more icons, then click on on "Applications" button, I don't see any HelloWorld icon, and I don't see any up/down arrows that indicate there are more icons. Am I missing something obvious? Here's what I see:

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/O2EgfLK-19N8nssbdatyhg?authkey=Gv1sRgCIjcnNLmhbWgeQ&feat=directlink

Thanks In Advance for any help.

- Chris

Comment: Try clean and build active blackberry configuration

Comment: Also try delete all dmp files in simulator folder and run clean.bat

Comment: Thank you, coldice. Your suggestion "Try clean and build active blackberry configuration" helped me clean out dead apps when "Erase Simulator File" | "Erase All" seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select File -> Load COD and then choose your application cod file. After that your application will be in Home->Downloads Folder on your Device.