# App don't show any changes after deploy to simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am new to blackberry and I am developing an app.
Suddenly it does not show any changes in the simulator as i change my code.
My cod file size 256 kb.
What should i do to correct this problem?
As I add new class to it, jar and other files get automatically deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Review similar questions:
[BlackBerry - Changes are not getting reflected in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168387/blackberry-changes-are-not-getting-reflected-in-my-app)
[BlackBerry JAR file problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673296/blackberry-jar-file-problem)
[Application is not loading in simulator using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388604/application-is-not-loading-in-simulator-using-eclipse)
[BlackBerry HelloWorld deploys in Eclipse under 8130 simulator but not 950](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249799/blackberry-helloworld-deploys-in-eclipse-under-8130-simulator-but-not-950)

Also remember to look into console (Alt+Shift+Q, C) for any errors.

Comment: hi , Max i reviewed the above links and also perform some research regarding the topic what it not helps me.i am wondering why my jar and other files get deleted as i add new class to my project and as i delete the added class all files generated.
thanks for your answer............

Comment: And there is no errors in console during build or deploy? Is Project->Build Automatically checked?

Comment: yes build project is checked and there are no errors, but still it showing the same behavior.